# uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address

Tags: docker, socket

I have run docker build -t and created image and latter container.Now I am looking at my docker logs

```
uWSGI http bound on 0.0.0.0:9090 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:32824 (port auto-assigned)fd3
```

As I remember the UNIX socket serves for an inter-process communication,TCP/IP allows communication between processes over the network.

What does mean that uwsgi socket is bound to TCP address?Does it change its role or not?